# What do they mean with asyncMode?

Tags: java, concurrency, fork-join

Directly from this [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html):

> This class provides adapt methods for Runnable and Callable, that may
> be of use when mixing execution of ForkJoinTasks with other kinds of
> tasks. When all tasks are of this form, consider using a pool
> constructed in asyncMode.

What does it actually mean `asyncMode` in this context? And how can I construct a pool in `asyncMode`?

Answer (score 0):

Javadocs says:

> asyncMode - if true, establishes local first-in-first-out scheduling
>   mode for forked tasks that are  never joined. This mode may be more
>   appropriate than default locally stack-based mode in applications in
>   which worker threads only process event-style asynchronous tasks. For
>   default value, use false.

Here is the constructor 
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool(int, java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler, boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool%28int,%20java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory,%20java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler,%20boolean%29)

Best regards.